# Four Lights (star like) Moving in a Line Together

Tags: artificial-satellite, identify-this-object

About 20 minutes ago, we saw four lights lined up and moving relatively quickly across the sky. These lights looked exactly like the stars around them - not red or blue or flashing or anything, just four stars at first glance. The spacing between them remained constant as they traveled in a straight line together (moving from West to East). The two in the middle were slightly closer to one another than the two in the front and back of the line, but the spacing was otherwise equal and constant - as if they'd been strung together on a line that was begging pulled forward.

They moved as quickly as a plane might when making a final approach to land, but there were no other lights visible around them and no sound. After watching for a minute, I called a friend out to reassure me I wasn't just seeing things, but they saw the same and described them as resembling stars more than anything else as well.

Do satalites travel in groups? Would they form a consistent line like this? That's the next closest thing I can think of, but I've never seen satalites quite that bright/large or traveling in locked step with others.

Could these have been military planes flying high enough to only appear as one whitish, twinkling light but still as fast as a lower flying plane? There is a naval Base not to far from us; that's the only other thing I can think of.

Comment: Gizmodo: [Breathtaking View of SpaceX Starlink Satellite ‘Train’ Triggers Wave of UFO Sightings](https://gizmodo.com/breathtaking-view-of-spacex-starlink-satellite-train-1835047155)

Comment: Helicopter often flight in line